# Minikube: use persistent volume (shared disk) and mount it to host

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, mount

I try to mount a linux directory as a shared directory for multiple containers in minikube.
Here is my config:

`minikube start --insecure-registry="myregistry.com:5000" --mount --mount-string="/tmp/myapp/k8s/:/data/myapp/share/"`

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: manual
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: myapp-share-storage
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  local:
    path: "/data/myapp/share/"
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - minikube
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: myapp-share-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: myapp-server
  name: myapp-server
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: myapp-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: myapp-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp-server
          image: myregistry.com:5000/server-myapp:alpine
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data/myapp/share
              name: myapp-share
          env:
            - name: storage__root_directory
              value: /data/myapp/share
      volumes:
        - name: myapp-share
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: myapp-share-claim
status: {}
```

It works with pitfalls: Statefulset are not supported, they bring deadlock errors :

- pending PVC: waiting for first consumer to be created before binding
- pending POD: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind

Another option is to use minikube persistentvolumeclaim without persistentvolume (it will be created automatically). However:

- The volume is created in /tmp (ex: /tmp/hostpath-provisioner/default/myapp-share-claim)
- Minikube doesn't honor mount request

How can I make it just work?

Answer (score 1):

Using your yaml file I've managed to create the volumes and deploy it without issue, but i had to use the command `minikube mount /mydir/:/data/myapp/share/` after starting the minikube since `--mount --mount-strings="/mydir/:/data/myapp/share/"` wasn't working.

Comment: It could be because it is `--mount-string`  and not `--mount-strings`